# How can I put the If Else statement here?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swift3

How can I use if else statement here, I have tried some but its error is cannot  assign value of type ()-> to type UIViewController -> UIScrollView

[image]

Comment: please clarify the actual question

Comment: post your code instead of image. and tell us what do you want to cehck using if condition.

Comment: How can I use the If Else statement here, I'm using infinity scroll bar, so PhotoStreamViewController and CollectionViewController are two different controller. after using one return the other one doesn't return anymore so its crashing

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "Type-Casting Patterns":
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html

```
if let viewController = controller as? PhotoStreamController {
    return viewController.photoStream
} else if let viewController = controller as? CollectionViewController {
    return viewController.collectionView
} else {
    return nil
}
```

or

```
switch controller {
case let viewController as PhotoStreamController:
    return viewController.photoStream
case let viewController as CollectionViewController:
    return viewController.collectionView
default:
    return nil
}
```